# web2py - ajax call returns 404 or fails to process parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web2py

I have a function defined in my controller:

```
def get_config_values():
    path = unescape(request.vars['path'])
    config = get_config_as_dict(path)
    return dict(config)
```

And in my view I use jQuery `$.ajax()` to call it in the view:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "{{=URL('get_config_values.json')}}", 
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
      data: {
         path: page_path,
      },
      error: function(x, y, z) {
         show_error(x.responseText, y, z);
         hide_drawer();
      },
      success: function(data) {
         $('#drawer_content').html(data);
      },
      type: 'POST',
   });
```

And put simply I cannot get this to work.

- if I use `type: 'POST'` then the function is called as expected but the `path` parameter never makes it through to the controller function (it is just `None`)
- if I change it to `type: 'GET'` web2py decides the function *does not exist at all* and returns a HTTP 404 (and this remains even if I remove `.json` from the URL). No errors in the web2py error log.

Web2py seems to behave quite strangely here - to get the POST working in the first place I had to explictly set `contentType: "application/json"` otherwise I'd see a 404 there as well, despite the `data:'json'` already there.

Has anyone else seen and worked around this behaviour? I don't care if the call is GET or POST, I just want it to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems. First, when a web2py action returns a dictionary, web2py looks for an associated view to execute (based on the path of the action as well as the extension). In this case, it will look for a view with the path `/views/controller_name/get_config_values.json`. If it doesn't find that view, it may attempt to use the `generic.json` view, but only if you have explicitly enabled the generic view via `response.generic_patterns` (in the scaffolding app, all generic views are enabled by default, but only for local requests). Otherwise, you will get a 404 error (if you inspect the body of the error message in the browser developer tools, you should see a message about an invalid view).

Second, to post JSON via jQuery, you have to convert your Javascript object to a JSON string:

```
data: JSON.stringify(
    {
        path: page_path
    }
),
```

With the above, you should now have the value of `page_path` in `request.vars.path` on the server.

Finally, if you request a `.json` URL from web2py, it will set the Content-Type response header to "application/json". However, based on your Javascript code, it appears you want to return HTML (given that you are placing the results into a div on the page). So, you should probably not use the `.json` extension in the request (you can also explicitly tell jQuery that the response is HTML by setting `dataType: 'html'`).

So, try the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "{{=URL('get_config_values')}}", 
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
  data: JSON.stringify({
     path: page_path,
  }),
  error: function(x, y, z) {
     show_error(x.responseText, y, z);
     hide_drawer();
  },
  success: function(data) {
     $('#drawer_content').html(data);
  },
  type: 'POST',
});
```

Then either create a get_config_values.html view that generates the desired HTML from the returned dictionary, or otherwise have the `get_config_values` function directly return an HTML string.

If you instead do want to return JSON to the browser, then you will need to change your `success` callback to process the JSON before attempting to place it in a div.

Comment: Thanks Anothony - I hadn't appreciated that web2py would go looking for a view if you returned a dict. I used `import json; return json.dumps(..)` in the action to return a string, rather than a dict, and it works fine.